# empImageURL does not render image

Tags: javascript, css

I pass this `d.meta.empImageURL`:

```
nodeEnter.append("def")
         .append("pattern")
         .attr("id", "image")
         .attr("x", "0%")
         .attr("y", "0%")
         .attr("height", "100%")
         .attr("width", "100%")
         .attr("viewBox", "0 0 512 512")
         .append("image")
         .attr("x", "0%")
         .attr("y", "0%")
         .attr("height", "512")
         .attr("width", "512")
         .attr("xlink:href", 'd.meta.empImageURL');
```

but it's didn't show the photo any idea?